# Immersion locally injective?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, differential-geometry, manifolds

I was wondering whether any immersion is locally injective?-This definitely sounds natural and I guess that it is true, as the derivative of an immersion is globally injective. Thus, there cannot be an area where our immersion is constant. Am I correct about it?-Probably this would imply that we can write any immersion locally as a graph of a function, right?

Comment: Every immersion is locally a embedding.

Comment: Just for reference, a proof of the previous commentary is given in "Analysis on manifolds", J.R. Munkres, Lemma 8.1 p.64

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the Inverse Function Theorem to prove that, in suitable local coordinates on both manifolds, an immersion is locally of the form $$f(x_1,\dots,x_k)=(x_1,\dots,x_k,0,\dots,0).$$

Comment: what I don't understand about this is the following: If $f(x_1,x_2) = (x_1,x_2,0)$ for example, then the metric tensor is just the identity matrix, right? But doesn't this mean that the Gauß curvature is also zero by the Theorema Egregrium? So we just showed that locally we can always make the Gauß curvature vanish, I don't understand how this is possible for let's say a sphere.

Comment: You're mixing differential topology and differential geometry. No one said that this coordinate chart is a local isometry.

Comment: I don't understand: Isn't your argument that there is a reparametrization $\phi$ such that $f \circ \phi = (x_1,x_2,x_3,..,0,...0)$ for any surface? From this we can calculate a metric tensor and this one tells us that the Gauß curvature is locally zero. But this problem also arises if I use Fermi coordinates for example. Do you mind explaining me the difference between reparametrization and this type of new coordinate system a little bit more, cause I really think I am making a huge error there.

Comment: Consider the immersion $f(x,y)=(x,y,x^2+y^2)$. To obtain the form above in appropriate coordinates, we need to change coordinates on the ambient $\Bbb R^3$ by $\psi(x,y,z)=(x,y,z-(x^2+y^2))$. The map $\psi$ is not an isometry of $\Bbb R^3$, so we are changing the induced metric on our immersed surface. (Indeed, as you pointed out, by changing the metric on $\Bbb R^3$, we've made the curvy paraboloid appear flat.) As I said, such changes of coordinates are *not* allowed in the setting of differential geometry.

Comment: ah, so a reparametrization is a change of coordinates of our surface, without changing the ambient space (allowed in differential geometry, cause curvature and so on is preserved). and there is the possibility to change the coordinates in $\mathbb{R}^3$, which is not allowed in differential geometry, but gives us nice ways to write down the first fundamental form, but the problem is that curvature and so on changes. i hope i got it now.

Comment: Right. You can change coordinates on the surface, and then you get different local expressions for the *same* metric tensor and second fundamental form, for example, but if you change coordinates on the ambient space, you would need to compute the  metric tensor in those new coordinates.

Comment: thank you, that helped quite a lot.